# Existe diferença entre list e "symmetric array destructuring"?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem

Eu estava procurando sobre uma nova sintaxe, que foi implementada no PHP 7.1, chamada de *Symmetric array destructuring*, de acordo com a [documentação do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring).

Basicamente, isso permite "desestruturar" um array, bem parecido com o JavaScript.

Exemplo:

```php
[$a, $b] = ['a', 'b'];
var_dump($a, $b); 

// string(1) "a"
// string(1) "b"
```

Porém, eu já sei que o `list` já fazia isso a bastante tempo.

Exemplo:

```php
list($a, $b) = ['a', 'b'];

var_dump($a, $b); 

// string(1) "a"
// string(1) "b"
```

Eu tenho umas dúvidas sobre isso:

- A atribuição feita *Symmetric array destructuring* e `list` trata-se da mesma coisa com sintaxe diferente?
- Existe alguma diferença entre as duas? Performance, processamento interno e afins?
- `list` pode se tornar *deprecated* com essa nova implementação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O PHP possui a *construção de linguagem* [`list()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.list.php), que é usada para desestruturar valores de dentro de um array. Ou seja, com `list()`, você pode desempacotar valores de dentro de um array sem utilizar utilizar o índice ou chave *após* o array.

Exemplos:

```
<?php
$userInfoPair = array("John Doe", 50);

list($name, $age) = $userInfoPair;

var_dump($name); //=> string(8) "John Doe"
var_dump($age); //=> int(50)
```

Ou, se os valores do array estiverem determinados por chaves:

```
<?php
$userInfo = array(
  "name" => "John Doe",
  "age" => 50
);

list("name" => $name, "age" => $age) = $userInfo;

var_dump($name); //=> string(8) "John Doe"
var_dump($age); //=> int(50)
```

Pode-se verificar, então, que, assim como `array()`, o `list()` não é, de fato, uma função, mas sim uma *construção da linguagem*.

E assim como o `array()`, que recebeu a nova sintaxe de colchetes, o `list()` também. Desse modo, não creio que exista diferença entre as respectivas novas sintaxes (com os colchetes), já que fazem exatamente a mesma coisa. A [própria documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring) afirma que se trata apenas de um *shorthand syntax* como uma *alternativa* à sintaxe de `list()`.

O "problema" que devem ter enxergado para justificar a introdução dessas novas sintaxes era ter que ficar digitando `array()` ou `list()` quando se quisesse construir ou destruir um array. Também (suposição minha) poderiam ser facilmente confundidos com funções, o que não é tecnicamente verdade.

Então, como nada muda "internamente", é uma mera questão de estética. Não há como negar que a sintaxe é bem mais sucinta:

Exemplos (correspondem aos dois anteriores, em ordem):

```
<?php
$userInfoPair = ["John Doe", 50];

[$name, $age] = $userInfoPair;

var_dump($name); //=> string(8) "John Doe"
var_dump($age); //=> int(50)
```

E:

```
<?php
$userInfo = [
  "name" => "John Doe",
  "age" => 50
];

["name" => $name, "age" => $age] = $userInfo;

var_dump($name); //=> string(8) "John Doe"
var_dump($age); //=> int(50)
```

> `list` pode se tornar *deprecated* com essa nova implementação?

É a mesma coisa que perguntar se a construção `array()` pode se tornar *deprecated*. Como muito código legado depende dessas construções, *acho* que não. No entanto, não posso afirmar com total certeza.